# How to filter by a list of URLs with the Google Analytics API?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to get pvs from some URLs in my homepage. But I can't use Regular expression. For example, filters='ga:pagepath=~/hoge/*'. Because there are URLs below /hoge/ I want to acquire and don't want to. So I want to use a list of URLs i want to acquire.

```
def get_results(service, view_id):
return service.data().ga().get(
    ids='ga:' + view_id,
    start_date='2015-01-01',
    end_date='2016-12-31',
    metrics='ga:pageviews,ga:avgTimeOnPage',
    dimensions='ga:pageTitle,ga:week',
    sort='-ga:pageviews’,
    max_results='10000',
    filters='ga:pagepath==url'
    ).execute()
```

url is a list of some URLs.

Answer (score 0):

as I see you use a Python list. This list should have the structure as below

```
mypages = ['ga:pagePath=~myregex','ga:pagePath=~myregex2']
myfilter = ','.join(mypages)
```

This is a kind of simple implementation. The ',' comma means 'or' for the ga filters. But be careful with the usage of 'or' together with 'and' rules. More information [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters)

Comment: thank you for answer. i tried this,but i got this error.｛TypeError: Parameter "filters" value "'ga:pagepath=~does not match the pattern "ga:.+"｝

Comment: My mistake. The correct field is 'ga:pagePath' I will be editing. Also there is a tool where you can check your API calls. .[link](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) Also you might need to escape the regex depending on which API library you use.